Get Azure Pipelines to install test environment from pyproject.toml instead of requirements_dev.txt
As mentioned in the title, I'm hoping to get Azure Pipelines to be able to install its test environment from pyproject.toml instead of a separate requirements_dev.txt file, as it would help with reducing the number of dependencies lists that I'd have to maintain.
From looking in the .azure-pipelines folder, I was able to find the following script section in the ci.yml file that seems to be responsible for the installation of the test environment:
  - script: |
      set -eux
      pip install --disable-pip-version-check -r "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/src/requirements_dev.txt"
      pip install --no-deps --disable-pip-version-check -e "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/src"
    displayName: Install package

Would replacing /requirements_dev.txt with /pyproject.toml be sufficient to get Azure Pipelines to read from pyproject.toml, or will I have to perform other tweaks in addition to that?
Thanks in advance!


Would replacing /requirements_dev.txt with /pyproject.toml be sufficient to get Azure Pipelines to read from pyproject.toml, or will I have to perform other tweaks in addition to that?

pip install -r command is not compatible with pyproject.toml files, it only works with requirements.txt files.
Instead, you can use python -m pip install . (assumes that your pyproject.toml file is located in the root of your repository.) to install the dependency.
My sample devops yaml based on github repo:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
- script: python -m pip install .
  displayName: Install depenency

- script: python -m unittest discover -v -s test
  displayName: Test



That's great, thank you for confirming that it's possible, and for providing an example of how that section of the script could be re-written! :D
